# How to get the payload information from jfrog webhook trigger on jenkins

Tags: jenkins, jenkins-plugins, artifactory

I'm setting up a jenkins job which will be triggered whenever a artifact is deployed in jfrog. I have followed the steps present in the below documentation and i was able to trigger the job.But unfortunately, I'm not able to get the variables values.I'm not sure how to see the payload which we are receiving on the jenkins side to pull the required variables.

https://www.eficode.com/blog/triggering-jenkins-pipelines-on-artifactory-events

My pipeline:

```java
pipeline {
    agent any
    
    triggers {
        GenericTrigger(
            genericVariables: [
                [key: 'ARTIFACT_NAME', value: '$.artifactory.webhook.data.name'],
                [event: 'EVENT_NAME', value: '$.artifactory.webhook.event']
            ],
            causeString: 'Triggered on $ARTIFACT_NAME'
        )
    }

    stages {
        stage('Hello') {
            steps {
                echo 'Hello World'
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Jenkins job logs:

```
java.lang.NullPointerException: Variable name
    at com.google.common.base.Preconditions.checkNotNull(Preconditions.java:204)
    at org.jenkinsci.plugins.gwt.GenericVariable.<init>(GenericVariable.java:31)
Caused: java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
    at sun.reflect.GeneratedConstructorAccessor6020.newInstance(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.java:45)
    at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:423)
    at org.jenkinsci.plugins.structs.describable.DescribableModel.instantiate(DescribableModel.java:330)
Caused: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Could not instantiate {event=EVENT_NAME, value=$.artifactory.webhook.event} for org.jenkinsci.plugins.gwt.GenericVariable
    at org.jenkinsci.plugins.structs.describable.DescribableModel.instantiate(DescribableModel.java:334)
    at org.jenkinsci.plugins.structs.describable.DescribableModel.coerce(DescribableModel.java:474)
    at org.jenkinsci.plugins.structs.describable.DescribableModel.coerceList(DescribableModel.java:585)
    at org.jenkinsci.plugins.structs.describable.DescribableModel.coerce(DescribableModel.java:458)
    at org.jenkinsci.plugins.structs.describable.DescribableModel.buildArguments(DescribableModel.java:409)
    at org.jenkinsci.plugins.structs.describable.DescribableModel.instantiate(DescribableModel.java:329)
    at org.jenkinsci.plugins.structs.describable.DescribableModel.instantiate(DescribableModel.java:272)
    at org.jenkinsci.plugins.pipeline.modeldefinition.CommonUtils.instantiateDescribable(CommonUtils.java:131)
    at org.jenkinsci.plugins.pipeline.modeldefinition.CommonUtils$instantiateDescribable.callStatic(Unknown Source)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.CallSiteArray.defaultCallStatic(CallSiteArray.java:56)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.AbstractCallSite.callStatic(AbstractCallSite.java:194)
    at org.kohsuke.groovy.sandbox.impl.Checker$2.call(Checker.java:194)
    at org.kohsuke.groovy.sandbox.GroovyInterceptor.onStaticCall(GroovyInterceptor.java:35)
    at org.jenkinsci.plugins.scriptsecurity.sandbox.groovy.SandboxInterceptor.onStaticCall(SandboxInterceptor.java:186)
    at org.kohsuke.groovy.sandbox.impl.Checker$2.call(Checker.java:192)
    at org.kohsuke.groovy.sandbox.impl.Checker.checkedStaticCall(Checker.java:196)
    at org.kohsuke.groovy.sandbox.impl.Checker.checkedCall(Checker.java:103)
    at com.cloudbees.groovy.cps.sandbox.SandboxInvoker.methodCall(SandboxInvoker.java:17)
Caused: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Could not instantiate {genericVariables=[{key=ARTIFACT_NAME, value=$.artifactory.webhook.data.name}, {event=EVENT_NAME, value=$.artifactory.webhook.event}], causeString=Triggered on $ARTIFACT_NAME} for org.jenkinsci.plugins.gwt.GenericTrigger
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have made it. We have to enable print post contents in configure jenkins job under generic webhook trigger option. Once done it started to display json payload in console log. After that we can add variables using jsonpath filter from payload

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 0):

I'd like to suggest a different approach using the [Jenkins Artifactory plugin](https://www.jfrog.com/confluence/display/JFROG/Jenkins+Artifactory+Plug-in):

You can configure a build trigger in the UI:
[image]

**Or** you can configure the build trigger in the pipeline:

```java
stages {
    stage('Artifactory configuration') {
        steps {
            rtServer(
                    id: "ARTIFACTORY_SERVER",
                    url: SERVER_URL,
                    credentialsId: CREDENTIALS
            )
        }
    }

    stage('Add build trigger') {
        steps {
            rtBuildTrigger(
                    serverId: "ARTIFACTORY_SERVER",
                    spec: "*/10 * * * *",
                    paths: "generic-libs-local/builds/starship"
            )
        }
    }
}
```

To get the path in Artifactory that caused the trigger you can do the following:

```java
environment {
    // The URL of the artifact in Artifactory, caused the job to be triggered.
    // May be empty if the build isn't triggered by a change in Artifactory.
    RT_TRIGGER_URL = "${currentBuild.getBuildCauses('org.jfrog.hudson.trigger.ArtifactoryCause')[0]?.url}"
}
```

Resources:

1. [Triggering builds](https://www.jfrog.com/confluence/display/JFROG/Jenkins+Artifactory+Plug-in#JenkinsArtifactoryPlugin-TriggeringBuilds)
2. [Triggering Builds in Declarative pipeline](https://www.jfrog.com/confluence/display/JFROG/Declarative+Pipeline+Syntax#DeclarativePipelineSyntax-BuildTriggers)
3. [Example](https://github.com/jfrog/project-examples/blob/master/jenkins-examples/pipeline-examples/declarative-examples/build-trigger-example/Jenkinsfile)

Comment: Hi @yahavi,the problem on the approach which you have mentioned is resource consumption.This is polling method and we need to keep poll and i need to set it up for 15 plus job and it will be intensive.Thats the reason i'm trying a webhook trigger approach